# C# how to pass a class instance to c# dll method?

Tags: c#, dll, .net-assembly

I loaded and got an instance form a dll by this code:

```
ApiClass api = new ApiClass(this);

Assembly SampleAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"C:\plugin1.dll");
Type myType = SampleAssembly.GetTypes()[0];
MethodInfo Method = myType.GetMethod("onRun");
object myInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
try
{
    object retVal = Method.Invoke(myInstance, new object[] { api });
}
```

and here is the code of IApi interface:

```
namespace PluginEngine
{
    public interface IApi
    {
        void showMessage(string message);

        void closeApplication();

        void minimizeApplication();
    }
}
```

I just copied the IApi to the dll project and build it. It is the code of dll:

```
namespace plugin1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public void onRun(PluginEngine.IApi apiObject)
        {
            //PluginEngine.IApi api = (IApi)apiObject;
            apiObject.showMessage("Hi there...");
        }
    }
}
```

but there is an error when I want to invoke the dll method:

`Object of type 'PluginEngine.ApiClass' cannot be converted to type 'PluginEngine.IApi'`

Comment: What is `myType` and what is `onRun`?

Comment: @p.s.w.g myType is `reflection` and `onRun` is the name of the method of the dll that I want to invoke it. Let me tell you that I searched about this error and I found most of the result that it is about the assembly reference that They are different. Thanks

Comment: What I mean is, please show the definitions of `reflection` (if that is the type you loaded into `myType`) and `onRun`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g this is the place that I defined them . What should I show actually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I just copied the IApi to the dll project

That's where you went wrong, you cannot copy the interface.  You are doing battle with the notion of *type identity* in .NET.  The identity of a type like IApi isn't just determined by its name, it also matters what assembly it came from.  So you have *two* distinct IApi types, the one in the plugin doesn't match the one in the host.

You need to create another class library project that contains the types that both the host and the plugin use.  Like IApi.  Add a reference to this library project in both your host project and your plugin project.  Now there's only *one* IApi.

Comment: thanks very much. Is there any way to do this or similar without using any library? I already can pass regular types(integer, long and ...) to the dll and invoke a method with this params. is there any way to pass complex type to dll without this way you said? thanks